# Warning using ListItem, FlatList inside ScrollView JSON

Tags: react-native

I get this warning when I tried using Flatlist inside View but same error occurs:

ERROR  VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.

AND item.name not show[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMgO7.png)

```
class Product extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    const {product_type} = this.props;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
          {
            <FlatList
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              data={product_type}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <ListItem
                  title={item.name}
                  subtitle={item.subtitle}
                  subtitleStyle={{color: 'gray'}}
                  bottomDivider
                  chevron
                  onPress={() =>
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail', {item})
                  }
                />
              )}
            />
          }
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: JSON  data: "product_type": [ {"id": 1,"name": "A" },{"id": 2,"name": "B"}, {"id": 3,"name": "C" },{ "id": 4, "name": "E"},{"id": 5, "name": "F"},{"id": 6, "name": "電H"}, {"id": 7, "name": "I" }, { "id": 8, "name": "J" } ],

Comment: What is your actual question? That message is just telling you that it doesn't make sense to put a flat list inside a scroll view because a flat list already is a scroll view of items basically. You could just get rid of your scroll view in this case and be just fine...

Comment: Del <ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}> is ok.

Comment: item.name no show text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <ListItem bottomDivider>
    <ListItem.Content>
      <ListItem.Title>{item.name}</ListItem.Title>
      <ListItem.Subtitle>{item.subtitle}</ListItem.Subtitle>
    </ListItem.Content>
    <ListItem.Chevron />
  </ListItem>
)
```